# Assign output from a Java program as bash shell variables

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

I have a Java program that outputs table names like so:

```
TABLE_EXAMPLE1
TABLE_EXAMPLE2
TABLE_EXAMPLE3
```

How can I assign the whole output as a variable in my bash shell so that I can continue to work with the table names? Ideally, I'd like to be able to create an array of table names from the output while suppressing the output from my Java program. In other words, I don't want my Java program to print out the output, but rather I'd like it stored in a bash variable.

Comment: Take a look at: [get result text from CLI command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154233/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reads the *stdout* of the *java* command into a exported variable.

```
export JAVA_OUTPUT=`java -jar application.jar`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign the output:

```
$ export MY_OUTPUT=`java -jar  MyJavaApp.jar`
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't have spaces around the `=`, at least in sh/bash.